# set of pointers with custom comparator

Tags: c++, pointers, set

```
struct classcomp ;      

typedef struct basic{
  int a ;
  set<base*,classcomp> b ;
  int c ;
} base ;

classcomp{
  bool operator() (const base& *lhs, const base& *rhs) const{
    return (*lhs).a < (*rhs).a;}
};
```

I want to create a set of pointers of datatype base with comparator function classcomp .where does my code gone wrong.Someone please help

Comment: `const base& *` is certainly wrong. It should be `const base*&`, a reference to a pointer, not a pointer to a reference. And honestly, the reference is overkill; pointer values will work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all I see in your code, you've several places where you're trying to use *dependent* declarations that don't exist yet. Fixing the various problems, one way to do this is:

```
struct base; //forward decl announces this will exist (sooner or later)

struct classcomp
{
    // uses forward decl from before in arguments. since we're
    //  using pointers, no other type info is required. we don't
    //  actually implement this yet (we can't, we don't know what
    //  "base" really is yet).
    bool operator ()(const base* lhs, const base* rhs) const;
};

// now we define "base". when the set is declared we provide it a
//  custom comparator type that has yet to be fully fleshed out, but
//  that's ok. we know what it *will* look like (it provides the
//  proper operator() overload).
struct base
{
    int a;
    std::set<base*, classcomp> b ;
    int c;
};

// now we know what a "base" looks like. we can use that to
//  implement the comparator operator () and finish what we 
//  started from before.
inline bool classcomp::operator()(const base* lhs, const base* rhs) const
{
    return lhs->a < rhs->a;
}
```

From there, you can use `base` as-is or derive from it and shove shove pointers of either into the `b` collection of a given `base` (which I wouldn't do, as I would have foisted all of this using smart pointers, but that's another issue separate from this question).

---

**Nested Comparator**

This can get considerably simpler if you nest the comparator within `base` in the first place, and you may want to consider that. In doing so it bring everything you need in one place:

```
struct base
{
    struct cmp_ptr
    {
        bool operator()(const base* lhs, const base* rhs) const
        {
            return lhs->a < rhs->a;
        }
    };

    int a;
    std::set<base*, cmp_ptr> b ;
    int c;    
};
```

Personally, I prefer the latter. If you need to use the comparator type somewhere else, it can be acquired using `base::cmp_ptr`, which is much clearer (to me at least) in its intent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great!! It worked.Thanks for the detailed explanation in snippet 1.

Answer (score 1):

`classcomp {...};` should be `struct classcomp{...};` and add a forward declaration of `struct base` or `class base`.

Or change the first template parameter of `std::set` to `basic` if you intend to do the same.

Also the type `classcomp` is not complete when you use it. Ensure that `struct classcomp` definition is available before class basic.

---

Offtopic but you can better re-write your classcomp less cryptic as:

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const base *lhs, const base *rhs) const {
        return lhs->a < rhs->a;
    }
};
```

Comment: A forward declaration won't do. The set needs complete types.

Comment: Oops, I was talking about the comparator but you're balking about `base`. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Define it this way

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const base& *lhs, const base& *rhs) const {
        return (*lhs).a < (*rhs).a;
    }
};

struct base {
    int a;
    set<base *, classcomp> b;
    int c;
};
```